# Let's get critical: Sep 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Islam Stack Exchange](http://islam.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Can I use a miswaak while fasting?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8687/can-i-use-a-miswaak-while-fasting)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Concept of life in exchange of life in Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/concept-of-life-in-exchange-of-life-in-islam)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Does Islam allow to force someone to maintain rules?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8792/does-islam-allow-to-force-someone-to-maintain-rules)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Global Islamic Calendar](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8870/global-islamic-calendar)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Is there free will of faith according to Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8933/is-there-free-will-of-faith-according-to-islam)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Best to wake up for fajr by alarm or by nyyah(intention)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8952/best-to-wake-up-for-fajr-by-alarm-or-by-nyyahintention)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [What are humans created from?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9037/what-are-humans-created-from)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Is it permitted to use perfumes while fasting?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8757/is-it-permitted-to-use-perfumes-while-fasting)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Red color clothes for men in Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8929/red-color-clothes-for-men-in-islam)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Difference between Taraweeh and Qiyaam al-layl](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8733/difference-between-taraweeh-and-qiyaam-al-layl)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 3)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some notes as I reviewed the questions:

- [Can I use a miswaak while fasting?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8687/can-i-use-a-miswaak-while-fasting)

Google corrects me when I search for this question:

> miswak while fasting

When I tell it to search for miswaak instead, Islam.SE turns up first.  It might be worth considering which spelling is most common for transliterations of Arabic words.  (Wikipedia is often a good [guide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miswak).)

As a non-Muslim, the question and the answer were close to impenetrable.  If the answer had not included the phrase, "or a toothbrush dampened with water", I would have had no clue what the issue was.  Generally, I'd say this is a good thing. (If a non-expert can't understand the question, it's often a sign the question is for experts.)  But looking around, I see virtually the same answer repeated over and over again.

Therefore, I'm guessing it's uncontroversially the right answer. But that implies the question is *trivial* for experts and the Arabic words make it seem more impressive than it really is.  You might consider creating a [jargon policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52/should-we-have-a-jargon-policy-guideline) so that the site is more friendly to [non-Muslims](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/how-can-we-make-this-site-more-friendly-to-non-muslims).  Alternatively, you could ask that questions (and thus answers) that are "off-the-beaten-path" somehow.  I'm afraid I don't see much about this question and answer that are *better* then what I find elsewhere on the internet.

- [Concept of life in exchange of life in Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/concept-of-life-in-exchange-of-life-in-islam)

Both the question and the answer are terribly unclear (perhaps because of language barriers).  If you voted anything other than "Needs Improvement", you probably misunderstood the point of the exercise.  It seems like the question is an interesting one to y'all, but to me, it sounds pretty vague.  I understand the answer, but it could use more detail and a friendly edit.

As an aside, [islamic-basis](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-basis) seems unproductive.  Maybe if it had a tag wiki, I'd understand, but it seems to me that every question on the site could be under that tag.

- [Does Islam allow to force someone to maintain rules?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8792/does-islam-allow-to-force-someone-to-maintain-rules)

One of the comments points out that the question is unclear.  Again, the language is a bit unclear.  But more importantly, there is a question about what a 22-year-old might mean by "forcing" his father to follow Islam.  It comes off as a question that should be asked of the OP's spiritual advisor.  (See related issues on [Judaism.SE](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312/perhaps-the-community-moderators-should-enact-a-more-strict-policy-regarding-hal) and [Christianity.SE](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255/pastoral-advice-questions).)

- [Global Islamic Calendar](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8870/global-islamic-calendar)

An interesting question and one that Google finds readily.  But it's not clear from the voting which answer is better.  There was comment correcting an astronomical error in one answer, but the answer was never edited to fix the error.  I'm left slightly more confused than when I started.  Remember, this site is supposed to be a long-term resource for people who find it in the future and not just a way for individuals to get their questions answered.

- [Is there free will of faith according to Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8933/is-there-free-will-of-faith-according-to-islam)

Looks like a contentious issue with no easy solution.  The question looks excellent to me.  The answers, as a rule, look well thought out.  But the voting is practically non-existent.  [Reward](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/181/68) your fellow contributors for working hard on a difficult question!

- [Best to wake up for fajr by alarm or by nyyah(intention)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8952/best-to-wake-up-for-fajr-by-alarm-or-by-nyyahintention)

It seems like this question isn't specific to Islam.  But the answer is great and the question does show up when I search Google.

- [What are humans created from?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9037/what-are-humans-created-from)

Looks like a solid question with a partial answer.  Perhaps it is, as mentioned by a commentator, a duplicate?

- [Is it permitted to use perfumes while fasting?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8757/is-it-permitted-to-use-perfumes-while-fasting)

Like the use of a miswaak question, the internet has no problem giving up the answer.  The question could use some editing.  [Ezati's answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/8759/138) adds quite a bit to Islam.SE's content.  It's a lot closer to "Excellent" in my opinion that many of the other questions.

- [Red color clothes for men in Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8929/red-color-clothes-for-men-in-islam)

Looks like another [old chestnut](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/old_chestnut) of a question.  There are lots of answers out there.  Unfortunately, the one answer here simply copied an answer from elsewhere.  This question needs much improvement.

- [Difference between Taraweeh and Qiyaam al-layl](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8733/difference-between-taraweeh-and-qiyaam-al-layl)

A poor answer is almost as bad as no answer at all; worse, since a user might assume this site contains mostly, or only, bad answers.

---

I'm a little disappointed in this evaluation.  Your traffic really picked up for Ramadan, but I'm not convinced that the site's quality was maintained. I know from reading the site that many of you *can* write and answer well, but I saw far less of that in this sample of questions.  If you have any ideas or suggestions, please raise them on meta.