# Salam in beginning of question

Tags: discussion

I think I should ask this question in meta.

Most people begin question with salam (which is okay) but half of that have typo and that are instead of Assalaamu 'Alaikum (or Assalamualaikum) are like salam olykum of salam lyk (which changes meaning of salam), and are needed to be edited to right. So what can be done to prevent such thing?

Comment: Any kinds of greetings are unnecessary as they are irrelevant on SE network also check [help/behavior]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best solution would be to [not welcome salams *at all*](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/107/22):

> I strongly encourage anyone reading this to abstain from adding unnecessary salutations to their questions and answers. This isn't a discussion board, answers are not replies, and if the majority of each question's excerpt quoted on the front page of the site is the same then you've thrown away what should have been an eye-catching introduction to your question...

That said, in the more general case of people using the "wrong" transliteration for Arabic terms (which is hardly limited to greetings), you have to remember the fact that the only "right" way to say "Assalaamu 'Alaikum" is "السلام عليكم‎‎" (other examples at "[Wrong spelling that may change meaning](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/11171/22)" and "[Muhammad, Mohammad, Muhammed, Mohammed, Mohamed, or Mohumed?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/23709/22)")

We generally prefer to keep a [loose standard of transliteration](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3/22) for consistency, but if the only *problem* with a question is that they're transliterating it *differently* (note: "differently" is not the same as "wrongly") then editing the post to fix *only that* is probably just a waste of time (aka noise), as is arguing with them to use a "better" transliteration.

And if you *are* going to correct someone's transliteration, [don't just stop there](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1796/22): Fix as many problems in the post as you can (and in my experience, there's almost *always* more than the one).

Answer (score 3):

Avoiding greetings has been consistent in my experience throughout StackExchange.  The StackExchange software is designed to automatically edit them out:

> We now automatically remove salutations from posts as they are entered.
>
> I got really tired of performing this edit over and over, so anything matching the form of [*snip*] is removed automagically at the time of submission to the server. --  [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989)

[Arguments against them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021) include: (a) obstructs question preview, (b) takes time to read and parse, (c) interferes with search engine snippets.

From the [Help Center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/behavior):

> **Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.**
>
> Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. If you use an additional signature or tagline, it will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers.
>
> Your user page belongs to you — fill it with information about your interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!