# Shouldn't these two tags [Aqeedah and Belief] be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tag

[aqeedah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aqeedah) and [belief](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belief) **mean the same** and they have the **same types of questions**.

I think [belief](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belief) should be made **synonym** to [aqeedah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aqeedah).

Comment: I'd be very glad if any moderator responds to my call.

Comment: Aqidah and faith are coherent ,aqidah could be a 'faith' but faith does not always mean as aqidah.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked through a number of the [belief](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belief) questions, and I'm just not seeing it; "Aqidah" and "Belief" might be synonyms, but in this context it refers to a particular *type* of belief, not just any old thing that happens to be or could be believed.

For example, questions like [Why in Islam there are prescriptions regarding health? but not Penicillin?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/12622/22) and [Should a Muslim believe in Dinosaurs?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/269/22) are tagged [belief](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belief) but they don't feel like [aqeedah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aqeedah) questions at all.

Rather than synonyming/merging these prematurely, I think the best course of action here is to figure out how they're even being used (and how or even *if* they should be used; i'm not entirely convinced [belief](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belief) is focussed enough to be worth keeping): Update the tag wikis accordingly, and clean up the outliers. Once we know how the tags are actually used and intended to be used, then we can revisit whether or not they're overlapping.

I have, however, gone ahead and renamed [aqeedah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aqeedah)→[aqidah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aqidah) as per [Rebecca's suggestion](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1903/22).

Comment: This is a good point. If we define the two tags accordingly then we might show some difference.

Answer (score 1):

1. Can someone who's a native Arabic speaker (or close to it) confirm there's no problematic language nuance here?  Wikipedia writes:

   > Aqidah... is an Islamic term meaning "creed".
   >
   > A [creed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creed) (also known as a confession, symbol, or statement of faith) is a statement of the shared **beliefs of a religious community** in the form of a fixed formula summarizing core tenets.

   This seems okay.
2. This makes sense as per:

   > Using the proper vernacular is an important part of setting the right tone for the site. Certainly, questions involving simpler concepts are welcome, but you should not be targeting and reaching out to "curious onlookers" specifically. -- [Robert Cartaino ♦](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/94/17163)
3. The tag [belief](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belief) shouldn't be on some questions: [1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/26223/17163) [2](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38441/17163) [3](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24006/17163) [4](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16945/17163) [5](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16562/17163) [6](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16541/17163) [7](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/14581/17163) [8](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/12622/17163) [9](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/8244/17163).  This one doesn't need [aqeedah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aqeedah): <strike>[1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/381/17163)</strike>. Removed.

This change passes my sanity checks.

---

Also...

- If this is implemented, can we also change the spelling to [aqidah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aqidah) as per the [transliteration protocol](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3)?  [Done now](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1919/17163): [aqidah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aqidah)
- While we're at it, can we think up a [tag excerpt](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts) for this tag?  "...a short blurb that describes when and why a tag should be used on this site specifically."  The Hinduism.SE [belief](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belief) tag excerpt is half-decent.  Maybe we can start with the following adaptation and improve it over time:

  > For questions about the Islamic belief system, e.g. the afterlife, predestination, angels.  Can be used in conjunction with denomination tags to limit the scope.

  *Update*: Done now.  I changed it to the above.  Feel free to improve.

  (See also: [belief](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belief), Christianity.SE; [hashkafah-philosophy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hashkafah-philosophy), Judaism.SE; [belief](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belief), Buddhism.SE.  But these don't seem appropriate tag excerpts.)

Comment: "what happens after death" is only one part of *aqidah*; the term generally encompasses things like *tawhid* and *al-ghaib* as well.

Comment: @goldPseudo: I wrote "e.g." as in "for example", but perhaps I should list another example to make that more obvious.

Comment: aqeedah refers to any belief - it could be true or false. so yes perhaps they should be synonymous. Our aqeedah for example entails the six articles listed in Hadith of Jibreel